# uglify.js + base64 embedded url incorrectly transpiling

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

I have an app that is embedding a small svg file into some css, and that css is in turn being pulled in to a javascript file as part of a component. if i *don't* uglify the code, everything works as expected, and i get something like this:

```
background: url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg id=%22Layer_1%22 data-name=%22Layer 1%22 xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 ...
```

however, once I uglify this code, the `%22` is replaced with `\'`, which unfortunately for me, IE11 can't understand, and therefore my image does not appear.  I've been poring over the uglify docs and trying various config changes to no avail.  Does anyone know how to fix such an issue or what configuration I could possibly use?

FWIW, this is running in a webpack 1 build (again, unfortunately for me)